# React Native how to create a VictoryPie from nested data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, victory-charts

In my React Native application, I am accessing data from my store in the following form:

```
Array [
  Checkout {
    "date": 2020-12-27T13:24:08.734Z,
    "id": "Sun Dec 27 2020 08:24:08 GMT-0500 (EST)",
    "items": Array [
      Object {
        "productBrand": "Microsoft",
        "productCategory": "Gaming",
        "productId": "p1",
        "productTitle": "Xbox",
        "quantity": 2,
        "x": 1.815,
      },
      Object {
        "productBrand": "Apple",
        "productCategory": "Computers",
        "productId": "p2",
        "productTitle": "MacBook Pro",
        "quantity": 1,
        "x": 1.905,
      },
    ],
    "total": 3.720,
  },
  Checkout {
    "date": 2020-12-27T13:24:47.790Z,
    "id": "Sun Dec 27 2020 08:24:47 GMT-0500 (EST)",
    "items": Array [
      Object {
        "productBrand": "Apple",
        "productCategory": "Computers",
        "productId": "p2",
        "productTitle": "MacBook Pro",
        "quantity": 1,
        "x": 1.905,
      },
    ],
    "total": 1.905,
  },
]
```

I am trying to use `VictoryPie` to create a pie chart that shows `productBrand` weighted by the sum of `x` over all the objects. In this example, I would need a pie chart showing Microsoft and Apple, weighted by 1.815 and 2*1.905 = 3.81, respectively. Is there any way to do this without writing a separate function to calculate these sums? I would like the pie chart to update automatically every time new data is added to the store.

I tried this, where `history` is a variable containing the above array but no pie chart is produced.

```
<VictoryPie data={history} x={(data) => data.items.productBrand} y={(data) => data.items.x} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to do something similar, I ended up extracting the data I needed by using a nested for loop within the `useSelector` hook:

```
const allBrands = useSelector(state => {
    let allData = {};
    for (const key1 in state.history.history) {
      for (const key2 in state.history.history[key1].items) {
        if (allData.hasOwnProperty(state.history.history[key1].items[key2].productBrand)) {
          allData[state.history.history[key1].items[key2].productBrand] += state.history.history[key1].items[key2].x;
        } else {
          allData[state.history.history[key1].items[key2].productBrand] = state.history.history[key1].items[key2].x;
        }
      }
    };
    let dataArray = [];
    for (const prop in allData) {
      dataArray.push({ brand: prop, total: allData[prop] })
    }
    return dataArray
  });
```

Passing `allBrands` to the `VictoryPie` `data` prop produced the correct pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

[image]See my working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-victory-pie-chart-forked-kpe39?file=/src/index.js

Like this:

```
        x="productBrand"
        y={(data) => data.x * data.quantity}
```

Comment: thanks for the response - unfortunately this isn't working in React Native and doesn't draw a pie chart (it only shows the category labels layered over each other)

Comment: Weird. I copied the code to a react native sandbox and it did show a pie chart: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-forked-yh22j?file=/src/App.js. See my updated answer for the image

Comment: okay I see - that works given the array format you used, but this is different from the format that I am using (see original example)

Comment: What is that format then? Looks unfamiliar to me. Can't you just use JSON?

Comment: that is the format of the data in my store - an array of `Checkout` objects, each of which has an `items` field containing an array of objects, which contain the data we need for the pie chart. Ideally I would be able to extract this data from the store directly

Comment: Still confused. Can you provide a working sample for that data format? Some push/pop, access item at an index?